# Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: docker, graphite, graphite-carbon

I was installing the graphite on docker using steps given [here](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#docker), I I got follow error .

```
Digest: sha256:3136b19fcdb9162c642cc1d2821172948346651a46b41ab63cc05c2962ea85c9
Status: Downloaded newer image for graphiteapp/graphite-statsd:latest
7af4b99efeb4bb7d0bc1ba1d8b4556d812adc87bc720c035998eeb54116e57f4
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint graphite (de38efe3b7ee88976d044ffe9948839c8058b06408f46f9857e4e689d9883ce9): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)
```

Then I tried to install again but it gave me error that name already exists and I should remove it, I tried removing it using

but got following error

```
  Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint graphite (733da4f70dc2c2e54a4cfacde6546df24829ef6d788222c41d417392c1e4acb1): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
```

why I am not able to install graphite using docker ?

```
 docker rm /graphite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)
```

It means that something already exists on your host machine on port 80 what is related to your run command and this flag: `-p 80:80` it means that you want to map port 80 from inside container (right part) onto your host machine (left part).
Fix for you is to stop some service on port 80 (like Skype - common case on Windows or Nginx/Apache - common case on Linux) or change your mapping to e.g. `-p 8080:80` and access your service via localhost:8080

Comment: Wow , ran like a charm . Thanks a ton